# Probability and Counting Question: 8 People Choosing 3 Rooms under Conditions

Tags: probability, combinatorics

If there are eight people and three rooms, and each person chooses a room with equal probability (1/3), what is the probability that there is at least 1 person in each room?
I have tried solving the problem by using
P(at least 1) = 1 - P(none)
But in this case, there are three cases:

1. One room is empty
2. Two rooms are empty

Thus I decided that the solution wasn't neat.
If possible, is there a neat solution that computes the probability of having at least 1 person per room? It would be great if I have steps and a solution.
Thank you!

Comment: I've used a method by initially allocating 4 people in to 4 rooms but that gave me a probability over 1, which is obviously incorrect. I am struggling to find an approach

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: Re previous comment, each room has a **constraint** of at least one person.  If $T_k$ denotes the enumeration that **at least** $k$ constraints are violated : $k \in \{0,1,2,3\},$ then the number of ways that no constraints are violated is $T_0  - T_1 + T_2 - T_3.$  This would represent the numerator in the fraction that represented the probability.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong. Isn't the case when k = 0 the case where no constraints are violated? Why is T0 = T0 - T1 + T2 - T3 ?

Comment: Just a remark: there is no case where the three rooms are empty. Numerically I find  0.883486 if this can help you.

Comment: I've tried and got the following answer. Please correct if I'm wrong. P(one room being empty) = 3 rooms x (2/3)^8. the (2/3)^8 is basically the probability of the eight people avoiding that one room. P(two rooms being empty) = 3 choose 2 x (1/3)^8. Again, the (1/3)^8 is the probability of the eight people avoiding the two rooms, specifically when the eight people all end up in the same room. Now 1 - P(one room empty) + P(two room empty) = 0.882487426. Am I correct or wrong here?

Comment: No, $T_0$, which is the case that **at least** $0$ constraints are violated is equal to $(3)^8.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to give a structural way to think about the situation. Consider first the trinomial expansion:
$$
P(x,y,z):=
\left(\frac 13(x+y+z)\right)^8
=\left(\frac {x+y+z}3\right)^8
=\frac 1{3^8}
\sum_{\substack{0\le i,j,k\le 8\\i+j+k=8}}
\binom 8{i\ j\ k}x^iy^jz^k\ .
$$
Here the trinomial coefficients involved are given by the formula:
$$
\binom 8{i\ j\ k}=\frac{8!}{i!\; j!\;k!}\ .
$$
The combinatorial relation to the given people and rooms is as follows.
We let the first person enter the corridor with the three rooms $x,y,z$ in it. Her choice of the room determines the term with the same label from the first $(x+y+z)$ factor in the product $P(x,y,z)$. Now the second person enters the corridor, her choice of a room corresponds to a choice of a term in the second factor $(x+y+z)$. And so on. Our normalization factor $\frac 13$ makes $P(1,1,1)=1$, corresponding to a total probability one. So $\frac 1{3^8}
\binom 8{i\ j\ k}$
is the probability that finally there are $i$ persons in room $x$, $j$ persons in room $y$ and $k$ persons in room $z$.

Now let us write explicitly:

- The probability that the room $x$ remains empty is the sum of the coefficients in $P(x,y,z)$ where $x$ appears at power $0$, i.e. $P(0,1,1)$. Plugging in the zero instead of $x$ makes a zero evaluation for all $x^iy^jz^k$ with $i>0$. Similarly...
- The probability that the room $y$ remains empty is $P(1,0,1)$,
- The probability that the room $z$ remains empty is $P(1,1,0)$,
- The probability that the rooms $y,z$ remain empty is $P(1,0,0)$,
- The probability that the rooms $z,x$ remain empty is $P(0,1,0)$,
- The probability that the rooms $x,y$ remain empty is $P(0,0,1)$,
- The probability that all rooms $x,y,z$ remain empty is $P(0,0,0)=0$.

By the inclusion-exclusion principle, the probability to have at least one empty room is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
p&=
P(0,1,1)+P(1,0,1)+P(0,1,1)\\
&\qquad-P(1,0,0)-P(0,1,0)-P(0,0,1)\\
&\qquad\qquad+P(0,0,0)
\\
&=
3\cdot \left(\frac 23\right)^8
-
3\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^8\ .
\\
&\qquad\text{So the wanted probability is }
\\
1-p &=
1 -3\cdot \left(\frac 23\right)^8
+
3\cdot \left(\frac 13\right)^8
=\frac{644}{729}\approx 0.883401920438957475994513031\dots\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: This is the same as in the last comment of @god in the OP.